# How do I solve 404 prolem in wordpress using hostinger

Tags: wordpress, hosting, cloud-hosting

I was trying to make my Url Seo friendly after I attach my page keyword to my Url in the premier link section, I came across this.

I try to fix it by going back and removing the keyword that I attach to my Url in the premier link section but it not working ..

This section can be found by going to setting->select Premier link

`Oops, looks like the page is lost`.

Comment: Can you please put one screenshot for your problme?

Comment: Please disable the server cache and your .htacess file. then check